# Exact target campaign Asset object records insertion

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel

Is there any way to insert records in Exact Target 'Campaign Asset' object?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What's the scenario?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

These are the sample campaigns that we have created in our account.

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/v1/campaigns"
        }
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "createdDate": "2015-04-20T05:54:40",
            "modifiedDate": "2015-04-20T05:54:40",
            "id": "29",
            "name": "Annual Sale 2014",
            "description": "Yearly sale",
            "campaignCode": "a1234",
            "color": "0000ff",
            "favorite": false
        },
        {
            "createdDate": "2015-04-20T05:54:40",
            "modifiedDate": "2015-04-20T05:54:40",
            "id": "28",
            "name": "Annual Sale 2015",
            "description": "Yearly sale",
            "campaignCode": "a123",
            "color": "0000ff",
            "favorite": false
        }
    ]
}
```

To create sample Campaign asset, we tried the REST API https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/campaigns/associateAssetToCampaign.html with the following requests:

```
{
    "ids": [
        "a1234",
        "a123"
    ],
    "type": "EMAIL"
}


{
    "ids": [
        "a1234",
        "a123"
    ],
    "type": "EMAIL"
}
```

We are getting the following error:

```
{
    "message": "A general error occurred while trying to associate assets",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```